# Override returned values from Model

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to override values from Model->fetchAll() so it work globally. I have tried to override this in model, but does not work:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_OdbcPush extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    public function __get(string $col)
    {
        $res = parent::__get($col);
        if ($col == "lastrun") {
            $res = ($res == "1912-12-12 00:00:00+07" ? NULL : $res);
        }
        return $res;
    }
    //...
}
```

In a controller:

```
    $odbcModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_OdbcPush();
    $rs = $odbcModel->fetchAll( $select );
```

I want to override value returned from fetchAll(), find() etc when col name is "lastrun";

Comment: I don't get the question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to override value returned from fetchAll(), find() etc when col name is "lastrun";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, for community i share here :D
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html

So we have to overload Zend_Db_Table_Row and assign it to model/dbtable:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Row_OdbcPush  extends  Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{

     // do some override here

}


class Application_Model_DbTable_OdbcPush extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected    $_name = 'odbcpush';
    protected    $_primary = 'id';
    private      $_global = null;
    protected    $_rowClass = "Application_Model_DbTable_Row_OdbcPush";

    // etc

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're going about this isn't going to work. `__get` is used to get data from `protected` or `private` properties and typically used in conjunction with getters.

For example, if you implemented `__get()` in your `Application_Model_DbTable_OdbcPush` class you could do something like:

```
$model = new Application_Model_DbTable_OdbcPush();
//echo out the _primary property (primary key of the table)
echo $model->primary;
```

and expect it to work. Because `_primary` exists as a property in `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.

To do what you want to do you'll need to do it after the result set has been returned (unless you want to rewrite the whole Zend Db component). Just run the result set through a `foreach` and change the value of `lastrun` to whatever you want.

I tried to find a place to override the Zend Db components to do what you want, but it would involve to many classes.

Remember that when using DbTable classes, they only interact with one table. You'll need to duplicate code for every table you want to effect or you'll need to extend a base class of some kind.

You always have the option to use straight Sql to frame whatever query you can come up with.

Good Luck!

Comment: Using straight SQL can be done and also looping then change the value (foreach), but there are many code i have to change :( i hope there is a proper way to do this is a Model

Comment: @Superbiji I understand, but that is not how the magic method works. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: @Superbiji the way to make this more possible is to implement an entity/mapper model (also know as a domain model) Then you can pretty much do what you need in each entity model that you need.